# how to delete an element of array without duplicating elements?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to delete a student at a  certain index from an array so I am deleting this student and shifting the elements to the left but my problem is one element is duplicating. note that not all my array is full I am filling it through the program so maybe the last student is not the last element in my array '

```
 public static void removestudent(int index) {

        for (int j = index; j < employee.length - 1; j++) {
                employee[j] = employee[j + 1];
        }
        System.out.println("The student was removed successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use ArrayList?

Comment: when you are shifting to left you can make the last element as 0 or -1 if you want it to be empty

Comment: your input parameter should be `int index` not `String index`

Answer (score 3):

The value gets duplicated as you are assigning  `employee[j] = employee[j + 1];` so when loop terminates the  `employee[j + 1]` remains unchanged! so duplicate values. After loop assign `employee[j + 1]` to empty.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, looks like the last two elements, at positions employee[j] and employee[j+1] resp. are getting duplicated. 
You must remove the element at employee[j+1] because its already been copied to the location employee[j].

[image]

My recommandation is to use ArrayList, because it already handles this kind of situations.

_Thanks,
Bhushan

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void removestudent(String index) {
    int temp[];
    for (int j = 0; j < employee.length - 1; j++) {
      if(j<index){      
          temp[j] = employee[j];
       }else
       {
     temp[j] =employee[j++];  
     }
    }
    System.out.println("The student was removed successfully");
    employee = temp;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can follow different approach.simply like this....!

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String [] employee={"a","b","c","d","e"};
    Set<String> s =new  LinkedHashSet<String>();
    int index=4;
    for(int i=0;i<employee.length;i++)
    { if(i!=index)
    {
        s.add(employee[i]);
    }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("The student was removed successfully");
}
```